# Why can i scroll only once with ScrollView in React-Native on Android?

Tags: react-native

i am following a React-Native tutorial and the ScrollView just works once.After i stop scrolling, the scrollbar disapears (like suposped to) and if i try to scroll again, it doesn't scroll and doesn't get visible anymore.

UPDATE: I just noticed, that it does not work, if i run it in Expo Go directly from console by running "npm run android" and neither if i reload by pressing "r". BUT, if i go to "Home" in the Expo Go-App and click on the app in the bottom list, the scrolling always works.

Why is that?

PS: I removed my code, because it is not the issue. It happens also with the official example code here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/scrollview

UPDATE: The issue happens on Samsung Galaxy S23, but on Galaxy S10+ is works perfectly fine!